# Getting matching values from a c# _context and updating the matching fields

Tags: c#, razor

I have an Edit.cshtml that has 3 edit boxes (groupName, itemName, colour) and a save button. When the save button is pressed the details from the text boxes are sent to Controller.cs as a volume and the exact item is updated.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Volume volume)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Volumes.Update(volume);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();              

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Error");
    }
```

I wish to be able to go into the _context.Volumes and update any item that also has the same groupName to the value of the colour that was set on the Edit.cshtml (where the parameter volume has a groupName, itemName and a colour), something like this but how do i get the match in the _context?

```
foreach(var groupName in _context)??
{
??
}
```

Thank you for your help, much appreciated as I am new to c#, jquery, razor etc...

Comment: So what does this itemName?Do you want to update any item with the same groupname?

Comment: Yes update any item with the same groupname, they are just strings. Not sure how to loop thru the _context and get and modify the matching items. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get related items simply by using the where clause.

```
var items= _context.Volumes.Where(a=>a.GroupName==Volume.GroupName).ToList();

foreach(var item in items) item.Colour=Volume.colour;   

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```